# Jekins sh label: Arguments to "sh" must be explicitly named

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm aware of [Jenkins Pipeline sh display name/label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414921/jenkins-pipeline-sh-display-name-label/54676428#54676428)

But when using

```
sh "echo foo", label: "my step"
```

I'll get the following error:

```
Arguments to "sh" must be explicitly named
```

I made sure to have Pipeline: Nodes and Processes v2.28 installed and I'm using a declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it out myself, it must be:

```
sh script: "echo foo", label: "my step"
```